# Deploy Software via GPO, but also deploy configuration file

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows

When deploying software through a group policy, is there any special trick that will allow you to also deploy a separate, say config, file along with it?

Here's the specific problem: We have a software package to deploy, but that saves its configuration into an INI file. Is it possible to deploy the INI file along with the MSI (via GPO) so that the application is "pre-configured" so-to-speak?

Thanks in advance,
Beems

Comment: Knee-jerk answer: "repack the *.MSI file and include the *.INI you want"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not unless you re-build the MSI (with third-party software).

What you can do is distribute the file with Group Policy Preferences, or even with a computer startup script. I strongly suggest GPP, as it's very easy to set up.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of Group Policy Preferences. After reading, that should work perfectly. As a huge additional benefit, we can deploy only the configuration when it changes.